# Make IEnumerable Entity Framework result async Web API

Tags: c#, entity-framework, async-await, asp.net-web-api2

I have a Web API (not .core web API) method uses Entity Framework to return some records from the database. The result is IEnumerable Model and I would like to modify it to use Async/Await technique to improve the performance, but I don't know how! I tried to use **ToListAsync** but it did not work.

My Web API method code

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/student/{id}/")]
public IEnumerable<Student> Get(int id)
{            
    try
    {
        var db = new DBEntities();
        return db.GetStudentDetails(id);
    }
    catch(Exception exception)
    {
        _logger.Error(exception.Message);
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.ExpectationFailed);
    }
}
```

My Entity Framework function code:

```
public virtual ObjectResult<Student> GetStudentDetails(int id)
{
     var idParameter = id.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("id", id) :
            new ObjectParameter("id", typeof(int));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<Student>("sp_get_student_details", idParameter);
 }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain your reasoning why this method but async should be more performant?

Comment: Coz, it could be hit by multiple users at the same time.

Comment: ASP.NET (both core and framework) start a new process for every distinct call to a web API, therefore each users request will be handled in parallel, making this async will not change it

Comment: have a look to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48159449/how-to-make-entiy-framework-stored-procedure-asynchronous

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
public virtual async Task<ObjectResult<Student>> GetStudentDetails(int id)
{
      var idParameter = id.HasValue ?
      new ObjectParameter("id", id) :
      new ObjectParameter("id", typeof(int));

      return await ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<Student>("sp_get_student_details", idParameter);
}
```

Comment: [`ExecuteFunction`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.objectcontext.executefunction?view=netframework-4.8) is not an async method and cannot be awaited. This code won't compile.